# Why does this jquery ajax sometimes save and sometimes not?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax request like so...

```
var html = $('#minePit').html();
        $.ajax({
            data: {
                minePit: html
            },
            success: function() {
                alert('success!');
            }
        });
```

The data consists of a string around 7k characters in length. It is attacked to a click function. If the ajax is activated twice it successfully saves, but then fails to do so, why could this be?
The type is GET and it contains html tags and html entities.

The server side query,

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['minePit'])) {
$q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE accounts SET minePit = ? WHERE id = ?");
$q -> execute(array($_REQUEST['minePit'], $_SESSION['id']));
}
```

Session is set, like I said saves twice then fails.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe its something with the server side script.

Comment: show us the server side query

Comment: could you try using post instead of get

Comment: Ye I will try it, I didn't think maybe the url has a character limit?

Comment: first escape your input string    var html = escape($('#minePit').html());  then in your  success: function() include  data    success: function(data) and alert(data) and put echo in your server code to debug

Comment: Ok will try this, thanks, @redmoon7777 ye this worked but it is still buggy, post is better though good suggestion thanks.

Comment: @redmoon7777 added async: false and works great now! Thanks for all ya help!